# Vue input dropdown simple

Tags: html, vue.js, vue-component

I am trying to doing something really hard. I have a input field where I want a dropdown for values. In HTML it is super easy but in Vue it is quantum physics.

```
         <div class="control">
      <input id="domain_name"  list="domain_list"
        v-select :options="['Canada', 'United States']"
        v-model="form[i-1].countries.cities"
        class="input"
        type="text"
        placeholder="Text input"
        />

      
       </div>
```

My goal is to make my input dropdown like this

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/datalist

Can someone help me please, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Actually it's not that hard.

This HTML

```
<label for="ice-cream-choice">Choose a flavor:</label>
<input list="ice-cream-flavors" v-model="iceCream" id="ice-cream-choice" name="ice-cream-choice" />

<datalist id="ice-cream-flavors">
    <option value="Chocolate">
    <option value="Coconut">
    <option value="Mint">
    <option value="Strawberry">
    <option value="Vanilla">
</datalist>
```

Can be achieved like that:

```
<template>
    <label for="ice-cream-choice">Choose a flavor:</label>
    <input list="ice-cream-flavors" id="ice-cream-choice" name="ice-cream-choice" />
    
    <datalist id="ice-cream-flavors">
        <option v-for="option in options" :value="option">{{option}}</option>
    </datalist>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: 'Example',
    data() {
        return {
            iceCream: '',
            options: [
                'Chocolate',
                'Coconut',
                'Mint',
                'Strawberry',
                'Vanilla',
            ]
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

I've never used this type of select field .. therefore I have no idea how it behaves (in relation to v-model binding)

BTW: Maybe a [plugin component](https://vue-multiselect.js.org/) would be a better choice

Comment: I get this error tag <option> has no matching end tag.

  75 |      
  76 |      <datalist id="ice-cream-flavors">
  77 |          <option v-bind="option in options" :value="option">
     |          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  78 |      </datalist>

Comment: ok, seems that on option tag needs to have a matching end tag. see edit.

Comment: BTW. I just googled "vue datalist option" and here is the first result:
https://www.raymondcamden.com/2018/04/12/datalists-with-vuejs

Comment: I tried that and it does not work also I should not use external framworks.